# How to convert csv file containing network data into GML

Tags: r, network-programming, graph-modelling-language

I have a dataset containing network data of email conversations consisting of two columns representing the connections between agents.

The dataset can be accessed from [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/email.csv)

Since I'm using igraph in R I would like to convert this file to GML format.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you know how the output format should look like? Give us an example please.

Comment: unable to access the data from the link anymore, can you at least give an outline of what the file consists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hope that helps.

```
library(igraph)
my.data <- read.delim(url("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22681355/email.csv"), sep = '')
my.graph <- graph.data.frame(d = my.data, directed = FALSE)
write.graph(graph = my.graph, file = 'email.gml', format = 'gml')
```